# Dog drinks a lot of water and spits it back up

Tags: dogs, drinking

Recently, my puppy (a ~5.5 month old Pembroke Welsh Corgi) has started to drink a ton of water from his bowl (sometimes as much as half the bowl), and then a few minutes later, he will spit up some of the water.

It's usually a pretty small amount that comes back up (and it rarely has any solids in it, mostly just water).

I'm wondering if this is an issue that I should take him to the vet for, or if there's something I can do to make him stop drinking so much at once. Or possibly that he just needs to drink more often, in smaller amounts.

Comment: You might consider a [Lixit dog bottle](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=969&tbm=shop&sxsrf=ALeKk019lTkA5gb7_awBwisP6U8-K6ZQXQ%3A1592873208407&ei=-FDxXvzAGO-e_QbEm7bwDg&q=Lixit+Dog+Bottle&oq=Lixit+Dog+Bottle&gs_lcp=Cgtwcm9kdWN0cy1jYxADMgYIABAIEB46BAgjECdQkY8BWOewAWCfswFoAHAAeACAAWyIAeQHkgEEMTEuMpgBAKABAaoBD3Byb2R1Y3RzLWNjLXdpeg&sclient=products-cc&ved=0ahUKEwj8nImO25bqAhVvT98KHcSNDe4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5) or similar, as it might slow his water intake, giving him time digest more of the water and not overfill himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my last visit, I brought this up with my vet. He said that dogs have a natural "gag reflex", so that when their stomachs get too full, they can gag back up.

He said that the best way to combat this "problem" was to control the amount of water the dog gets at one time.

Comment: Please note that by limiting the amount of water that a dog can consume, it might cause them to drink more than they can take, because they are unsure of when they can next drink.